# Web Link does not open for user

Tags: hyperlink

I have a user who is having an issue with one of the hyperlinks in our 2013 instance.

The problem:

- When he mouses over the hyper link he gets `https&#58 ;//contoso.com/offers/YT23456`
- When I go to the same page and mouse over the link mine displays `https://contoso.com/offers/YT23456` which is correct.

For the user the hyperlink is not clickable. On the other hand, when I click on the link it takes me to another page as expected. Can someone please help with this issue?

**Note:** There is no space between 58 and the semicolon in the first link. I placed a space to display the error otherwise it would render correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have the user try different browsers. If a different one works - you know it's the browser, from there you can try to disable add-ins and re-test.  If it's an add-in you find you can disable it.

I can't recall the specific scenario at present but Office can cause URL issues with SharePoint.  Usually it's connected with documents - but it if you are not running the click to run version (Office pro plus) you may want to to attempt an repair on your Office installation as well.

Comment: Ok sounds good. I can have the user test with different browsers. How would I know which add-ins to even look at? I'm sorry i'm fairly new to SP and need a bit more assistance than the next. As far as Office we are running Office Professional Plus 2010.  Could you please advise?

Comment: I would disable all and test - if it works, then you know it's probably an add-in, so just start re-enabling them one by one until you find the one giving you the issue. I would try different browser first to be sure - if it happens in two different browser, that that's not your problem.